# IBM Notes database - Slow

Tags: database, lotus-notes

I am currently working with IBM notes and I realize that it is sometimes very slow. Our database runs on a Server and my question is: What if 100 users have a Notes client in which they access and edit documents(which are in a database from that server) at the same time. Would that cause slowness because too many people do too many actions on that server?

Comment: This question is wrong here, belongs to serverfault or superuser. Just one thing: We have servers, they have 2.000 concurrent users, and they are not slow at all (and these are "small environments" for Domino- servers). IF the application is slow, then a) the application is very bad or b) the server configuration is bad or c) the client configuration is miserable

Comment: @TorstenLink Thank you very much for taking time to anwser, may I know how much servers you got and which is the most active one an how big are the notes databases on that server.

Comment: I am consultant and know everything from single server environments to worldwide environments with 2.000 or more users per server... This question is to broad: The answer is "this is not normal". But a fix for it might involve a lot of analysis for the reasons for the slowlyness.

Comment: Torsten is correct. Properly designed Domino applications or perform well under loads from thousands of users as long as the hardware is adequate - and very modest hardware can easily handle 100 users. But if the application is poorly designed, or if the hardware is not up to the job, then of course it can be slow. An experienced Domino consultant would look at all aspects of the problem; there are far too many possible issues to consider and StackOverflow isn't designed for the type of detailed back-and-forth dialogue that would be required to help you narrow it down.

Comment: Agree with Richard. Applications running on Notes client exchange nothing but data with Domino server. All processing is done at client side. You may need an experienced developer to look at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the answers from the comments on my question and posted it as an
>   answer. Thank you @Torsten Link and @Richard Schwartz:

**Comment from @Torsten Link:**

This question is wrong here, belongs to serverfault or superuser. Just one thing: We have servers, they have 2.000 concurrent users, and they are not slow at all (and these are "small environments" for Domino- servers). IF the application is slow, then a) the application is very bad or b) the server configuration is bad or c) the client configuration is miserable

**Reply on above comment from me:**
@TorstenLink Thank you very much for taking time to anwser, may I know how much servers you got and which is the most active one an how big are the notes databases on that server.

**Answer from @TorstenLink:**
I am consultant and know everything from single server environments to worldwide environments with 2.000 or more users per server... This question is to broad: The answer is "this is not normal". But a fix for it might involve a lot of analysis for the reasons for the slowlyness.

**Comment from @Richard Schwartz:**

Torsten is correct. Properly designed Domino applications or perform well under loads from thousands of users as long as the hardware is adequate - and very modest hardware can easily handle 100 users. But if the application is poorly designed, or if the hardware is not up to the job, then of course it can be slow. An experienced Domino consultant would look at all aspects of the problem; there are far too many possible issues to consider and StackOverflow isn't designed for the type of detailed back-and-forth dialogue that would be required to help you narrow it down.